# Find an equation for a sinusoid with minimum and maximum

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

Here's my problem:

Find an equation for a sinusoid that has a minimum at (30°,-1) and an adjacent maximum at (75°,7).

Please help! I've tried everything I can think of, but I'm really drawing a blank here, and I need my answer before 6:30 tonight!

So I'm pretty confident that the amplitude = 3, and the midpoint = 4, but I still need period and/or phase shift...

Comment: Hint: if you increase the amplitude of $\sin x$ to 4 and move it up by 3, and make $1/4$ cycle be $45^\circ$, and move the phase so that minimum and maximum are exactly at $30^\circ$ and $75^\circ$, then cheer!

Comment: Well, I've studied sine curves before, so I know I need the basic things; amplitude, period, phase shift, and midline. But I've never seen a problem like this, and I don't even know where to start!

Comment: So my answer would be y = 3 sin(1/4x) + 4, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the half period of the $sin$ is the distance between consecutive local max and min. therefore half period $T/2 = 45^\circ = \pi/4 \to T = \pi/2.$ the sinusoidal is oscillating about the average value $\frac 12\left(7-(-1)\right) = 4$ and the amplitude is $7-4 = 3.$  putting all these together, we get $$y = 4 - 3\sin 4(t - \pi/24)=4-3\sin\left(4t - \frac{\pi}6\right).$$

Comment: Oh, that looks fantastic! Thank so much for the explanation, too! :D I feel much better about my answer now. This is a great site!